# How i can reduce curl in project

Tags: c++, curl

I have project with curl but size my file 720KB. This is a lot for me. I am use curl only for smtp, how i can reduce my file. I tried use defines discribed in `CURL-DISABLE.md` but that not worked, i think i configured them incorrectly. Can you give me instruction how i can reduce curl? My code of program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

#define CURL_STATICLIB
#include "curl/curl.h"

#pragma comment(lib, "libcurl_a.lib")

static size_t WriteCallback(void *contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp)
{
    ((std::string*)userp)->append((char*)contents, size * nmemb);
    return size * nmemb;
}

int main(void)
{
  CURL *curl;
  CURLcode res;
  std::string readBuffer;

  curl = curl_easy_init();
  if(curl) {
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://google.com");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteCallback);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &readBuffer);
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);

    std::cout << readBuffer << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

It work but a lot of size. [SCREEN_OF_FILE_IN_PATH](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EmEnE.png)

Comment: Looks like you are statically linking to it. Maybe switch to dynamic library? And enable all sorts of size optimizations and trimming unused sections in linker.

Comment: Yes you might try what @TanveerBadar suggested and additionally also build curl yourself as a dynamic library, disable everything you don't need and set your compiler/linker to optimize for size.

Comment: If that does not work you might try your OS's native api to retrieve a URL instead of curl, if cross-platform-support is not important in your case.